# Launch BASH script by clicking icon and preserve terminal icon

Tags: bash, shell-script, icons, desktop-file

My problem is pretty simple, but I must admit, I don't know any elegant solution. I have a problem, that I often accidentally click different icon that I wanted. It's really very unpleasant, so I've decided to write a bash script, which will ask me if I really want to launch the program ( especially Eclipse, because it's pretty large and so it takes lots of time to load ).

I had written it, then added its location to the **eclipse.desktop** file... And now there's my problem. The Eclipse launcher works, but if I launch only Terminal, Eclipse icon shows up instead of original Terminal's.

Do you know how could I solve this, if I wanted to keep my bash script working?

---

Here is my bash script **eclipseLaunch.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you really want to launch Eclipse? (yes = y)"

read answer

if [[ "$answer" = "y" ]]; then
    ~/.eclipse/eclipse
fi
```

And here is my **eclipse.desktop** file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"~/.eclipse/eclipseLaunch.sh; exec bash\""
Icon=/home/martin/.eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've solved it. After this solution I had to **restart PC**.

I've changed my **eclipse.desktop** file to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Exec=bash -c "~/.eclipse/eclipseLaunch.sh; exec bash"
Icon=/home/martin/.eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=true
```

And **eclipseLaunch.sh** to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you really want to launch Eclipse? (yes = y)"

read answer

if [[ "$answer" = "y" ]]; then
    nohup ~/.eclipse/eclipse &
else
    kill $PPID
fi
```